# robot_localization from map to odom does not move on Ubuntu-18.04 Melodic

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, ubuntu, robot-localization, tf-tree

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using `robot_localization`in my project. I'm fusing data from camera odometry, imu, depth sensor and usbl (XY position sensor) as odom0, , odom1, odom2 and imu0 respectively. I followed the instructions in configuring the parameters on [official documentation](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/index.html) and set the frames as a "fixed frame" and a "moving frame". In my case the moving frame is the `odom` frame and the fixed frame is the `base_link`.

[image: rviz]

The documentation tells me this should make the ekf_localization node publish the transform from map to odom if the `publish_tf` param is set to true.
The launch file both for the "fixed frame" and the "moving frame" is below together with the `tf tree`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
<param name="use_sim_time" value="true" />

 <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node"
     name="ekf_odom" clear_params="false">
    <param name="use_sim_time" value="true" />
    <param name="sensor_timeout" value="2.0"/>
    <param name="two_d_mode" value="false"/>
    <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
    <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
    <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_link"/>
    <param name="world_frame" value="odom"/>
    <param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
    <param name="frequency" value="10"/>

    <param name="imu0" value="/imu/data_w_orientation"/>
    <rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false,
                                   true,  true,  true,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   false, false, false]</rosparam>
    <param name="imu0_differential" value="false"/>

    <param name="smooth_lagged_data" value="true"/>


    <param name="odom0" value="/cam/odometry"/>
    <rosparam param="odom0_config">[false, false, false,
                                    true,  true,  false,
                                    false, false, false,
                                    false, false, false,
                                    false, false, false]</rosparam>
    <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>
  </node>

<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node"
    name="ekf_map" clear_params="false">
   <param name="use_sim_time" value="true" />
   <param name="transform_time_offset" value="0.2"/>
   <param name="sensor_timeout" value="2.0"/>
   <param name="two_d_mode" value="false"/>
   <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
   <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
   <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_link"/>
   <param name="world_frame" value="map"/>
   <param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
   <param name="frequency" value="10"/>
   <param name="smooth_lagged_data" value="true"/>

<!-- upload config files here -->
   <rosparam file="$(find ros_float)/config/au_au.yaml" command="load" />
   <rosparam file="$(find ros_float)/config/cov_config.yaml" command="load" />

   <param name="odom0" value="/usbl/pose_projected"/>
   <rosparam param="odom0_config">[true, true,  false,
                                  false, false, false,
                                  false, false, false,
                                  false, false, false,
                                  false, false, false]</rosparam>
   <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>
   <param name="odom0_nodelay" value="true"/>
   <param name="odom0_relative" value="false"/>

   <param name="imu0" value="/imu/data_w_orientation"/>
   <rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false,
                                  true,  true,  true,
                                  false, false, false,
                                  false, false, false,
                                  false, false, false]</rosparam>
   <param name="imu0_differential" value="false"/>

   <param name="odom1" value="/filter/fluid_pressure/depth"/>
   <rosparam param="odom1_config">[false, false, true,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   false, false, false]</rosparam>
   <param name="odom1_differential" value="false"/>

   <param name="odom2" value="/cam/odometry"/>
   <rosparam param="odom2_config">[false, false, false,
                                   true,  true,  false,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   false, false, false]</rosparam>
   <param name="odom2_differential" value="false"/>

 </node>
</launch>
```

**what I have tried to solve the problem so far:**

Someone already had the [same problem here](http://answers.ros.org/question/285601/robot_localization-asking-for-map-to-odom-transform/) but a clear answer was not provided. A small update was posted advising to add the following specification to the `.launch` file:

```
 <param name="transform_time_offset" value="0.2"/>
```

However it didn't work.

Following my previous posts here and here no answer was provided. Unfortunately I am still stuck with this problem and no `urdf` model is moving according to the moving frame.
The `odometry` does not show any particular uncertainty and in fact the arrow is still pointed in the middle of the `urdf` model.

On official documentation there is the presence of a dual EKF example and in fact it is possible to launch it from here `/opt/ros/melodic/share/robot_localization/launch/dual_ekf_navsat_example.launch` and exactly here it was provided the duality "fixed frame" and "moving frame".
I did it exactly as it said the example but still no luck

**UPDATES on tf_tree**

My `tf_tree` is the following

[image: tree]

Finally the small python script that does the transformation can be seen below:

```
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseWithCovarianceStamped
from sensor_msgs.msg import NavSatFix
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry

class TransformPose:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pub = rospy.Publisher('/usbl/pose_projected', Odometry, queue_size=10)
        self.pressed = False
        rospy.Subscriber("/usbl/latitude_longitude", NavSatFix, self.callback)

    def paramsReady(self):
        return rospy.has_param('/utm_zone') and\
               rospy.has_param('/origin_lon') and\
               rospy.has_param('/origin_lat') and\
               rospy.has_param('/origin_z')

    def callback(self,data):
        rospy.loginfo_once("received data lat lon usbl")
        if(self.paramsReady()):
            rospy.loginfo_once("Valid survey params found:  transform_pose starting")
            crs_wgs = proj.Proj(init='epsg:4326') # assuming you're using WGS84 geographic
            utm_zone = rospy.get_param("/utm_zone")
            crs_bng = proj.Proj(init=utm_zone) # use a locally appropriate projected CRS

            originLon = rospy.get_param("/origin_lon")
            originLat = rospy.get_param("/origin_lat")
            # then cast your geographic coordinate pair to the projected system
            xoff, yoff = proj.transform(crs_wgs, crs_bng, originLon, originLat)
            zoff = rospy.get_param("/origin_z",0)
            # input from NavSatFix
            lon = data.longitude;
            lat = data.latitude;
            x, y = proj.transform(crs_wgs, crs_bng, lon, lat)
            x = x-xoff
            y = y-yoff
            z = 0;

            # output message
            transformed_msg = Odometry()
            transformed_msg.child_frame_id = "base_link"

            if x== float('Inf') or y==float('Inf'):
                pass
            else:
                transformed_msg.pose.pose.position.x=x
                transformed_msg.pose.pose.position.y=y
                transformed_msg.pose.pose.position.z=z
                transformed_msg.header.frame_id="map"
                transformed_msg.pose.covariance = [5., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                                                   0., 5., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                                                   0., 0., 5., 0., 0., 0.,
                                                   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                                                   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                                                   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
                self.pub.publish(transformed_msg)
                if self.pressed:
                    self.button_pub.publish(transformed_msg)
                    self.pressed = False
        else:
            rospy.loginfo_once("Receiving odom message but urvey params not ready.  waiting...")
```

Please point in the right direction or advice on what the problem could be because as of now I don't have any additional idea on how to move on and make the `urdf` according to fixed-moving frame using `robot localization`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327495/robot_localization-from-map-to-odom-does-not-move-on-ubuntu-18.04-melodic/) by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2019-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have a bad frame configuration in your *map*-frame EKF.

Here's your *odom*-frame EKF:

```
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node"
     name="ekf_odom" clear_params="false">
  <param name="use_sim_time" value="true" />
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="2.0"/>
  <param name="two_d_mode" value="false"/>
  <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
  <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
  <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_link"/>
  <param name="world_frame" value="odom"/>
```

Here's your *map*-frame EKF:

```
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node"
    name="ekf_map" clear_params="false">
  <param name="use_sim_time" value="true" />
  <param name="transform_time_offset" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="2.0"/>
  <param name="two_d_mode" value="false"/>
  <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
  <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
  <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_link"/>
  <param name="world_frame" value="odom"/>          <!-- OFFENDING LINE -->
```

The `world_frame` in your *map*-frame EKF should be *map*, not *odom*. There's a [template config](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/melodic-devel/params/dual_ekf_navsat_example.yaml#L86) in the package.

There may be other issues, but that's a big one.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2019-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2